# What is the penalty of having ETH2 validator offline

Tags: proof-of-stake

i want to do participate in proof of stake.
i have just read https://ethereum.org/en/eth2/staking/ .

under "Risks" the site says

> Although you can earn rewards for doing work that benefits the network, **you can lose ETH for** malicious actions, **going offline**, and failing to validate."

now i wonder:
what is the issue about going offline exactly?
let's say my server has an uptime of 99%. in the staking-time my server is going offline 2 or 3 times due to a software-crash or a blackout or because my internet-service-provider has problems and it lasts some hours until my server is online and available for proof of stake again. what is the consequence? do i loose some of my staked eth in this case, and if yes: how many?

Answer (score 2):

[Here is an article of rewards and penalties for faulty validators](https://codefi.consensys.net/blog/rewards-and-penalties-on-ethereum-20-phase-0#:%7E:text=Rewards%20and%20penalties-,Slashing,blocks%20for%20the%20same%20slot). The rewards and penalty mechanics are very complex and the actual reward and penalty numbers depend on the network state.

There is no slashing (major) penalty for being offline - slashing is only for dishonest validators. However there are minor penalties for being offline. If your validator cannot stay online it will slowly bleed ETH. But you are not going to lose all of your staked ETH once.