# How to move a validator from VPS into DappNode?

Tags: validators, the-merge, vps

My DappNode stuck at customs.

**PROOF**

[image]

It will not arrive on time for the merge.

I want to do it, like an achievement, badge of honour, "I was there"

So... I will start on some VPS and then in a week migrate to my physical hardware.

## **HOW?**

Asking because I prefer to DYOR upfront rather than solving (potentially impossible) problems on the fly.

Surely this has been discussed, I just want to lean on your existing experience

**DOXXING MYSELF**

To say that you can afford 32 ETH to run a validator is genuinely doxxing yourself. I also have the [longest BTC address](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/72986/11112) in existence.

I neither confirm nor deny that I've first memorised the brainwallet and then intentionally not-unintentionally forgot a few bits.

**BUT**

I know it is easily brute-forceable if you know some magic keywords. In case you want to extort me (torture, under duress) it will buy me some time

Answer (score 0):

#### Just don't?

See this [Twitter conversation](https://twitter.com/marsxrobertson/status/1575842027128123392):

[image]

Also this: [What is the penalty of having ETH2 validator offline](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/90781/what-is-the-penalty-of-having-eth2-validator-offline)

> There is no slashing (major) penalty for being offline - slashing is only for dishonest validators. However there are minor penalties for being offline. If your validator cannot stay online it will slowly bleed ETH. But you are not going to lose all of your staked ETH once.

---

I have DappNode at home so when moving to a new location I can always take the physical hardware with me. No need to do temporary cloud migration.

The other way round - start with the cloud and then move to physical hardware - super convoluted, asking for trouble - **just don't**. My use case was super specific to participate in an airdrop but now it is gone and no longer relevant.